# Content lost in RecyclerView after scrolling only on cheap devices

Tags: android, android-listview, universal-image-loader, android-recyclerview

Im using `RecyclerView` to display a list of custom view, 
Custom view contain picture loaded by `Universal Image loader`
and text view

But some random contents(exactly text only) of the each custom view are lost after the scrolling the `RecyclerView` down and scrolling back **only on cheap devices.** With new device like nexus 7 and galaxy s4 works perfect.

I have exactly the same code as in the tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html

Comment: We need more information, like your adapter and your layout file.

Comment: Is it firstLine or secondLine that's missing?

Comment: This is completely random, no rules with line is disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of searching and debugging all it turned out that my code is correct.

The problem was very strange . From some reason the font color is random magical change to another on the cheap devices. Conclusion You can see in the picture below .

[image: When you change the background color , you can see a strange change the <code>TextView</code> .]

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue on Megafon Logon 1 SP-AI
and to make recyclerview visible I had to perform fake scroll after any changes in adapter.

Something like this:

`mList.smoothScrollBy(1, 0);`